# Custom XML Format with .Net

Tags: .net, xml

How to write an XML file in .Net with custom tags? The structure must be like the following:

```
    <ABC version="1" xmlns="http://anySchemaAddress">
       <Date>20140922</Date>
       <Contract>
          <Type>1</Type>
          <Key>1000012</Key>
          <ContractNumber>1234567X90</ContractNumber>
          <Value>661.00</Value>
          <HoldBackDate>20181231</HoldBackDate>
       </Contract>
    </ABC>
```

Is there any way to config the xml write in .Net, or do I need to write the File line by line?

Comment: There are at least three high level methods of writing xml files in .NET... `XmlDocument`, `XDocument` and `XmlSerializer`

Answer (score 0):

`XDocument` is an easy way to write custom XML files. Following code would create an XML file like the one you need:

```
XNamespace xmlns = "http://anySchemaAddress";

var doc = new XDocument(
    new XElement(xmlns + "ABC",
        new XAttribute("version", 1),
        new XElement("Date", "20140922"),
        new XElement("Contract",
            new XElement("Type", 1),
            new XElement("Key", "1000012"),
            new XElement("ContractNumber", "1234567X90"),
            new XElement("Value", "661.00"),
            new XElement("HoldBackDate", "20181231"))));
```

To save the document, use `doc.Save("path");`

As you can see, `XDocument` is highly customizable, you can write any element with any value.

Note: you will need the `System.Xml.Linq` namespace.